# SQLAlchemy left join using subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Lets say there's a table "posts" which contains blog posts, and another table "favorites" which links a username to a post. Many users can favorite a post, so the relationship is one post to many favorites.

I am trying to figure out the syntax to join posts to favorites, but I only want those favorites where the user is the current user.

I want some thing like:

```
current_user = 'testuser'
posts.query.outerjoin(favorites, and_(posts.post_id == favorites.post_id, favorites.username == current_user)).limit(10).all()
```

This get me really close, except it seems like the "favorites.username == current_user"  condition is basically getting ignored. This is what I am looking for in actual SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT * FROM favorites f WHERE f.user_id = 'testuser'
          ) ff ON ff.post_id = p.post_id
LIMIT 10
```

It's also worth mentioning that I have defined the relationship on posts like:

```
favorites = db.relationship("favorites")
```

And I have defined the foreign key on favorites like this:

```
post_id = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('posts.post_id'))
```

How can I accomplish this in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 4):

Really you just need to replace the `outerjoin` with `join`, and the filter would work just fine.

*Also, if your `favorites` table contains no additional information and only links `users` and `posts`, you should consider simply defining a [`Many to Many' relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many). In the documentation examples Parent/Child would be your User/Post.*

**Update-1:** just to answer second part of the question given your comment, the query below should give you an idea:

```
current_user = 2
subq = (db.session.query(favorites)
        .filter(favorites.user_id == current_user).subquery('ff'))
q = (db.session.query(posts, subq.c.score)
     .outerjoin(subq, subq.c.post_id == posts.post_id))
q = q.order_by(subq.c.score.desc())
for post, score in q:
    print(post, score)
```

Comment: The favorites table also contain the score - e.g. 1-5 how much the user likes the post.

Also, when I use the join, only the posts that have been favorited come up. Instead I would like all posts to get returned, but I want only those favorites which pertain to the current user. i.e. if a post is not favorited by the current user, then it should still come up but with no favorite objects listed. If the post is favorited by the current user and several other users, only the current user's favorite should show.